# On the conditional expectation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $r_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be a random variables that takes values $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ with equal probability. Let $a_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be  real valued numbers.

How to find (or bound from above) the following conditional expectation for $p\geq 2, \quad T\in R$:
$$
E\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^na_ir_i\right|^p \big| \sum_{i=1}^nr_i=T\right)?
$$

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that there is a closed form expression for this conditional expectation?

Comment: Questions like these give me the impression that the power of probability theory is sometimes overestimated. Is there a reasonable context in which you were asked (or asked yourself) to find this out?

Comment: With the help of probability and combinatory I have been able to calculate similar expectation when $r_i$ are $\pm1$. The upper bound in the present question would be satisfactory as well.

Comment: Is there any independence assumption on $(r_i)$?

Comment: No, no other assumption on $(r_i)$