# Can multinomial theorem be used in the expression?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, combinations

Can multinomial theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem be used in the conditional expectation in [On the conditional expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805338/on-the-conditional-expectation)? I.e. can I expand:

$$
E\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_ir_i\right|^{2k} \big| \sum_{i=1}^nr_i=T\right)=\sum_{k_1+\ldots k_n=2k}\frac{(2k)!}{k_1!\ldots k_n!}a_1^{k_1} \ldots a_n^{k_n}E\left(r_1^{k_1}\ldots r_n^{k_n}\big | \sum_{i=1}^nr_i=T\right)
$$

Comment: No, because $|x+y|^p \neq (x+y)^p$.

Comment: Ok, if we put assumption that the sum is non-negative. Would it be true?

Comment: As long as $\sum a_i r_i$ is almost surely nonnegative, then the result is correct, basically because condition expectation is linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the sum is negative, $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_ir_i\right|^{2k} = \left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_ir_i\right|^{2} \right)^k = \left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ir_i\right)^{2} \right)^k = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ir_i\right)^{2k}.$$
Your equation follows by using the [linearity of the conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties).

Comment: So, even though I have dependence on $r_i$, I can use the multinomial Theorem?

Comment: Yes. Imagine first expanding the expression inside the conditional expectation, then using linearity to "pull out" the sum and the constants. Linearity holds irrespective of the dependence.